# Jetty Continuation handler registration

Tags: jetty, handler, continuations

I'm writing a servlet that runs commands on an exsisting java system ("MyJavaSystem") and write output to user.
The commands executed are asynchronous and servlet must return each result line to client.
I'm using Jetty and Continuation.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long timeoutMs = 6000;
    public MyJavaSystem sys;
    Continuation continuation = null;

    public MyServlet (MyJavaSystem a) { sys = a; }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {
        String commandResult = (String)request.getAttribute("results");
        if (commandResult == null)
        {       
            continuation = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(request);
            if (continuation.isInitial())
            {
                continuation.setTimeout(timeoutMs);
            }
            if (continuation.isExpired()) 
            {
                response.getWriter().write("Timeout");
                return;
            }       
            if ( request.getParameter("command") != null && ! request.getParameter("command").equals("") ) 
            {
                // Execute command
                sys.execute(request.getParameter("command"));

                // suspend the request
                continuation.suspend();

                // ---- Here I need to register myHandler and myHandler2
            }
        } else {
            // Write command result line to user
            response.getWriter().write(commandResult); 
            continuation.complete();
        }

    }
    // Called by sys every new line in command output
    public void myHandler(String commandOutput)
    {
        if (continuation != null)
        {
            continuation.setAttribute("results",commandOutput);
            continuation.resume();
        }
    }
    // Called by sys when the command is done
    public void myHandler2(String commandOutput)
    {
        if (continuation != null)
        {
            continuation.setAttribute("results",commandOutput);
            continuation.complete();
        }
    }
}
```

The sys.execute() is a non-blocking call (due to system implementation) and myHandler(), myHandler2() functions will be called by the external java sys during command executions.

How can I register this handlers?
If i run the code above i get:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-726
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: IDLE, initial 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation.dispatch(AsyncContinuation.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation.resume(AsyncContinuation.java:892) 
    at mypackage.MyServlet.myHandler(MyServlet.java:22)
```

Comment: I've been running into the same exceptions using Jetty 8.10. Have you figured out the cause of the exception?